# Move items from one listbox to another without duplicating

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

[image]

I have a userform with two listboxes side by side. I want the left listbox to contain a large list of items, and the user can select those they want and send them to the listbox on the right. This does not remove the items from the listbox on the left. Items on the left are unique.

I don't want users to be able to send the same item twice to the list on the right, so I have the following sub to check for duplicates first:

```
Sub ToRight(ctrlLeft As control, ctrlRight As control)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim there As Boolean

    For i = 0 To ctrlLeft.ListCount - 1
        If ctrlLeft.Selected(i) = True Then
                there = False
                For j = 0 To ctrlRight.ListCount - 1
                    If ctrlRight.List(j) = ctrlLeft.List(i) Then
                        there = True
                    End If
                Next
                If there = False Then ctrlRight.addItem ctrlLeft.List(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

For each selected item in the left listbox, it will check every item in the right listbox to see if there is a match, and only add it if there is no match. That is very slow once there are around 1000 entries in the list (it can happen) and the userform actually hides itself after running the code (5 seconds). I have to minimize and re-maximize the Excel application for the userform to show again (and it is modal).

How can I send items to the right listbox without such a painful loop? Or how can I make the loop less expensive so it doesn't crash the userform?

Comment: When you move it to the right listbox, remove it from the left and vice versa so that they cannot add the same item twice. Simple as that :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have thought of doing that, but the items are ordered according to our nomenclature, the order has a sense and users would expect to see the listed items in that order. If I remove it from the left list, and a user decides they don't want to have that item after all, sending it back to the left will screw up the order by putting it on the end

Comment: If you can explain the order then maybe we can put it back at the same position?

Comment: Or you can prefix the items by 1., 2. 3. That ways you will know which position it belongs to?

Comment: The list is taken from the workbook written at the top of the userform, it is not alphabetical. I took that list in a variant array before populating the listbox, but there is no inherent logic (for a computer) for the list's order. ---- although a hidden prefix could be good! How can i make it hidden though?

Comment: See my previous comment. Either you can add a prefix or store the list in a hidden sheet. The list will be in col B and the positions will be in col A. So when the user moves it back, simply check the position in the hidden sheet ;)

Comment: Could also maintain a parallel copy of the data in the right listbox in a dictionary, solely for lookup purposes. Every time you add to the listbox, add to the dictionary. Every time you remove, remove from both. Then you can use `Dictionary.Exists` to very quickly check whether the item is already in the list or not. Note that this obviously trades off memory usage for computational speed, but for ~1000 rows the memory usage will be pretty minor.

Comment: Might also look at using `Listbox.SelectedItems` instead of `Listbox.Selected` so you can more easily identify what items to check (instead of looping through the entire set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Scripting Dictionary is ideal for comparing multiple list.

```
Private Sub btnCopyUniqueSelectedItems_Click()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dictItems As Object
    Set dictItems = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 0 To ctrlRight.ListCount - 1

        dictItems.Add ctrlRight.List(i), vbNullString

    Next

    For i = 0 To ctrlLeft.ListCount - 1
        If ctrlLeft.Selected(i) = True And Not dictItems.Exists(ctrlLeft.List(i)) Then

            ctrlRight.AddItem ctrlLeft.List(i)

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simpler and faster loop, I made a template like the following image. I listed the column headings of the worksheet on ListBox1. The selected Items from ListBox1 are moved to ListBox2 with the button. The pointed columns to by items on ListBox2 are copied to the other sheet.

[image]

```
If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
MsgBox "Choose an listbox item from left", , ""
Exit Sub
End If

deg = ListBox1.Value
    For m = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If deg = CStr(ListBox2.List(m)) Then
        MsgBox "This item already exists in ListBox2", vbCritical, ""
    Exit Sub
    End If
Next
ListBox2.ListIndex = -1
 ListBox2.AddItem ListBox1.Value
ListBox1.RemoveItem (ListBox1.ListIndex)
Call animation_to_right
```

[Template can be viewed and downloaded here](https://eksi30.com/excel-copy-columns-with-userform/)